# How do I configure my DNS so that it checks a website for my public ip address with ddclient?

Tags: minecraft

How do I configure my DNS so that it checks a website for my public ip address?

I have set up a DynDns hostname that updates the public ip address every hour, so I can connect to that without a problem, but now I need to configure a static internal IP? (I can't make a static public address because my isp doesn't provide it). I know /etc/resolv.conf comes into it somewhere, can somebody explain to me how this works?

And I know that my interfaces need to be configured so my network card uses a static internal ip that is linked to the public IP that is always changing? Can someone help me and explain how I can do this,
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to mess with `resolv.conf` or any of your internal DNS settings.

For what you need to achieve, I've found it easiest to make all the changes in my router by adding a reserved internal IP address for the machine(s) that I want to have the same internal IP address all the time. Almost every router has some type of Web interface that you can access through the router IP, so if your LAN is running on addresses in the 198.162.0.x range, the router will be at 192.168.0.1. Because each router is different, it's hard to give exact directions on where to find where you set the reserved IP addresses; look in the LAN settings section, or it may be plainly visible in the menu options. Once you have your machine set on a reserved IP in the router, you can set up Port Forwarding for the specific ports you want routed to that machine: if you're running a Minecraft server, you would forward port 25565 to it.

Many routers also have options for using dynamic DNS services like dyn.com in which you enter your account info for dyn.com, and if and when your public IP changes it notifies dyn.com of the change and they will update your DNS A records with the new public IP of the router.